# What Julia does at the exceptional points?

Tags: julia, numerical-methods, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm looking at the numerics of some matrices that depends on a parameter `x`. The matrix has real eigenvalues for certain values  `x`, but for other values I have a degeneracy in both eigenvalues and eigenvectors (the occurrence of exceptional points).

One of the simplest examples to get an exceptional point is with the matrix:

```
julia> h=[1 1im; 1im -1]
2×2 Array{Complex{Int64},2}:
1+0im   0+1im
0+1im  -1+0im
```

The eigenvalues are zero, as they should be

```
2-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
-2.22045e-16+0.0im
0.0+0.0im
```

However, I would like to know why Julia give me the eigenvectors:

```
julia> b[2][:,1]
2-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
-0.0-0.707107im
0.707107+0.0im     

julia> b[2][:,2]
2-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
0.707107+0.0im     
0.0+0.707107im
```

Since in this case the eigenvalue is zero, I think it doesn't really matter what is the associated eigenvector. But if the eigenvalues coalesce somewhere in the 
complex plane, do I really get two equal eigenvectors?

Is there an specific way to treat this cases in Julia?

Answer (score 2):

The kernel of your matrix consists of multiples of `(1,i)'`, which is what you get. As the matrix is not the zero matrix, it has rank 1 and thus also co-rank 1, the eigenspace has dimension 1. The generalized eigenspace is the full space, you get `A*(1,0)' = (1,i)'` so that in that basis `((1,i)',(1,0)')` the linear operator has the matrix `[[0,1],[0,0]]`, its Jordan normal form.

Comment: Can you always find the generalized eigenspace in these cases?

Comment: Yes, the algorithm for that can be found anywhere the Jordan normal form is discussed in-depth.